# Drupal 7 ob_get_clean(): failed to discard buffer of _shutdown_function

Tags: drupal-7

After updating the [Creative theme](https://drupal.org/project/creative) to version 1.3 and deleting a few unused modules, I noticed a message when I log out:

```
Notice: ob_get_clean(): failed to discard buffer of _shutdown_function (2) in theme_render_template() (line 1520 of ... theme.inc).
```

The website layout changed and the content of some blocks is displayed on the top page (wrong place) as shown below.

[image: Screenshot showing the misplaced content]

There is not much info on this problem on the web and I've [reported this](https://drupal.org/node/2083001) as a Drupal bug, but I thought I'd ask here too. If anyone has ideas how to deal with this issue, please post your suggestions.

Comment: You may want to provide some more information here: what version of Drupal you are running for example.

Comment: I am using Drupal 7.23. I am not able to find the source of the problem. It also affects the css styling of the search block. What is _shutdown_function (2)?